# Proof of Inverse Function Theorem in Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds

Tags: multivariable-calculus, manifolds

In the proof of Inverse Function Theorem, Spivak states
[image]

Lemma 2-10 is given below. Can anyone explain why the statement above is correct? Thanks!

> **Lemma 2-10** : Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a rectangle and let $f : A \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be continuously differentiable. If there is a number $M$ such that
> $| D_j f^i (x) | \leq M$ for all $x$ in the interior of $A$, then
> $$
> |f(x)-f(y)| \leq n^2 M |x-y|
> $$
> for all $x,y \in A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall right at the beginning of the proof Spivak shows that $Df(a)$ is the identity $\pi$, so that $$|D_jg^i(x)|=|D_jf^i(x)-D_j\pi^i(x)|=|D_jf^i(x)-D_jf^i(a)|\lt\frac{1}{2n^2}.$$ So, letting $M=1/2n^2$, we can apply **Lemma 2-10** to conclude $$\big|f(x_1)-x_1-\big(f(x_2)-x_2\big)\big|=|g(x_1)-g(x_2)|\leq\frac{1}{2}|x_1-x_2|.$$

Answer (score 0):

I finally understand it now. The explanation by @Moed Pol Bollo is not accurate. Inequality (3) is correct since $f$ is $C^1$. Because $\lambda=Df(a)=I$, we have $D_jg^i(x)=D_jf^i(x)-D_jf^i(a)$. Hence, $M$ is actually $\frac{1}{2n^2}$ here. Applying Lemma 2-10 yields,
$$|g(x_1)-g(x_2)|\le n^2 M|x_1-x_2|=\frac{1}{2}|x_1-x_2|.$$

Comment: Yeah sorry, was typing on mobile and omitted the 2’s.

Comment: @MoedPolBollo Thank you. I accepted your answer.